# @XmlElement("name") ^ symbol: class XmlElement gradle error?

Tags: spring-mvc, gradle, java-8, build.gradle

I'm trying to make a compilation of gradle, I'm getting this error, anyone know how to solve?

**Note** the application works normally running on the eclipse of this error only when carrying out the build of the app.

```
E:\VirtualBox\projeto\nextinfo\web>gradle build
:utils:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:utils:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:utils:classes UP-TO-DATE
:utils:jar UP-TO-DATE
:web:compileJava
  E:\VirtualBox\projeto\nextinfo\web\src\main\java\br\com\nextinfo\multimedia\web\model\DisplayDigital.java:8: error: package com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.annotation does not exist 
import com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.annotation.XmlElement;
```

**My gradle file.**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

ext.springVersion= '4.1.7.RELEASE'
ext.jacksondataTypeHibernate4 ='2.5.3'
ext.easycriteriaVersion ='3.0.0'
ext.hibernateCoreVersion ='4.3.10.Final'
ext.hibernateValidadeVersion ='5.1.3.Final'
ext.springDataVersion ='1.8.0.RELEASE'
ext.mysqlConnectionVersion= '5.1.6'
ext.servletApiVersion ='2.5'

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
    compile project(':utils')
   compile"javax.servlet:jstl:1.2"
   compile "org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:2.1.2.RELEASE"
   compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:   servletApiVersion
   compile group: 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-layout-     dialect', version: '1.2.9'
   compile 'com.github.dandelion:datatables-thymeleaf:0.9.3'
   compile 'com.github.dandelion:datatables-core:0.8.4'
   compile 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:4.0.0.GA'
   compile 'net.sourceforge.html5valdialect:html5valdialect:2.1.2'
   compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: '4.0.2.RELEASE'
  compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '4.0.2.RELEASE'
   compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '4.0.2.RELEASE'
   compile 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:2.1.2.RELEASE'
  compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: springVersion
  compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: springVersion
  compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: springVersion
   compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version:springDataVersion
   compile "org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc4"
   compile group: 'uaihebert.com', name: 'EasyCriteria', version: easycriteriaVersion
   compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: hibernateValidadeVersion
   compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: hibernateCoreVersion
   compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: hibernateCoreVersion
   compile 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1'
   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate4:2.6.2'

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell gradle how to resolve all the dependencies.  You can use any repo you like.  You do this by providing a repository closure like this:

```
.....
ext.servletApiVersion ='2.5'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
....
```

So this will try and use a maven repo to resolve the dependencies.  There is more information here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the problem is in the java 8 with gradle, I added more dependence and changed aa note of the internal note of dependence, functioned normally.
I hope this helps others who have the same problem.